# write data to text file by python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a script to split IP from a log file :

```
f = open("list.LOG" , "r" , encoding="utf8")
x = f.readlines()[6:99]
for i in x:                                  
    y = i.split(",")[4].split(":")[0]                      
    print(y)

f.close()
```

out put:

```
168.62.187.180
168.62.187.180
168.62.187.180
168.62.187.180
113.23.50.88
113.23.50.88
113.23.50.88
113.23.50.88
137.135.120.84
137.135.120.84
137.135.120.84
137.135.120.84
```

I want to remove duplicate IP and write to file "IP.txt" but I do not have idea.someone can help?thanks

Comment: can you please format the code ?

Comment: you can remove duplicates with the `set` class  and writing into a file with the `write()` file method.

Comment: Can you please fix you code appearance?

Comment: i fixed ,have any idea?bro

Comment: do you want to keep order or you don't care about it?

Comment: keep order and I can not write line by line.any idea?

Comment: a sample of the input file would be a plus...

Comment: alright,How can I write y to txt file? when I write,It is only the last line,foget duplicate,I just want to write y,pls

Answer (score 2):

**A bit explanation:**

Your first question is,

> I want to remove duplicate IP?

Here, you can use a set() on list , but then your requirement is to keep the unique items in order, so `set(x)` is not a good idea.

what you can do is,

- take a list/set
- in each iteration, check if the current ip is in the above list/set
- if exists, then skip the ip
- if not, then add it, and write the ip to the output file.

Your second question is,

> How do I write them to a file?

This is even simpler, you know how to open/close you file, so all you have to know is just how do you write the content. Use `f.write(content)` where `f` is the file object.

Try this:

```
f1 = open("list.LOG" , "r" , encoding="utf8")
x = f1.readlines()[6:99]

f1.close()

f2 = open("result.txt" , "a+" , encoding="utf8")

result = set()

for i in x:                                  
    y = i.split(",")[4].split(":")[0]                      
    if y not in result:
        result.add(y)
        f.write(y + '\n')
f2.close()
```

I would refactor the code like below:

```
with open("list.LOG" , "r" , encoding="utf8") as f1, 
         open("result.txt" , "a+" , encoding="utf8") as f2:

    result = set()
    x = f.readlines()[6:99]
    for i in x:                                  
        y = i.split(",")[4].split(":")[0]                      
        if y not in result:
            result.add(y)
            f.write(y + '\n')
```

Using `with` while opening the file will take care of closing the file itself, so you don't need to close it explicitly.

It has a fancy name `Context Manager`.

Comment: I would use an aux `set` instead of the actual list so it would be faster for the lookup. `aux = set()` then `if y not in aux: aux.add(y); result.append(y)`

Comment: also I would explain how it takes care of the duplicates, since our friend @Pavan has trouble understanding how it works.

Comment: also you could use context managers (`with open ...`) instead of `open/close` (nitpicking, already upvoted)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, btw, I like your idea, but what if I just skip the list; check the element in the set, if not then add it, and write the line to the file, instead of writing it as a whole. Do you think it's a better idea? Or the I/O will take longer time?

Comment: yes, you can stream the output so if the list is big it doesn't take a lot of memory. no need for a `list` after all. The output file is the aim.

Comment: my code: f = open("list.LOG" , "r" , encoding="utf8")
x = f.readlines()[6:99]
for i in x:                                  
    y = i.split(",")[4].split(":")[0]                      
    print(y)
    with open("output.txt","w") as z:
        z.write(y)

f.close()
In file output.txt It's only the last line :137.135.120.84 not all line.So,how can I write all the line to output.txt

Answer (score 1):

`result = list(set(y))`

if you want to preserve order :

```
result = []
seen = set()
for i in y:
    if i not in seen:
        result.append(i)
        seen.add(i)
```

Then write the list to the file.

```
with open("IP.txt" , "a+" , encoding="utf8") as f:    
    f.write('\n'.join(result))
```

Comment: your old version wasn't closing the file and wasn't formatted properly. So I helped you :) Check "ctrl+k" to add the spaces instead of backquoting multilines (not very convenient)